# I need an opinion and maybe a clarification about my work on the following problem:

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Problem: Suppose that $m_1,m_2,...,m_t$ are positive integers and $a_1,a_2,...,a_t$ are integers.

What condition on $m_1,m_2,...,m_t$ is necessary to guarantee that there is an integer x such that $x ≡ a_i $ mod $m_i$ for all intergers i in the range $1\leq i\leq r $.

My idea:
I will choose for presentation x=1, $a_1=14$ and $m_1=13$.

Now let k be any positive integer. So that $a_n=a_1+k*(n-1)$ where n>0.
Similarly let $m_n=m_1+k*(n-1)$.

Now for any n, 1 ≡ $a_n $ mod $m_n$.

The solution is that $m_1,m_2,...,m_t$ is pairwise coprime.

In my presentation if I have k=2 then my m's will not be pairwise coprime.

Could you please explain why the answer is pairwise coprime and why will my idea not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you are given the $a$'s and $m$'s and asked to find $x$.  If the $m$'s are pairwise coprime, the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) guarantees a solution.  If they are not, there may not be a solution.  As an example, take $m_1=4, m_2=6$, which have common factor $2$.  Then if $a_1=1,a_2=2$ there is no solution because the first forces $x$ to be odd and the second forces $x$ to be even.

Comment: You said "the first forces x to be even and the second forces x to be odd" is it not the other way around?

Comment: @BurLeXyOOnuTz:  Yes, a brain glitch. Fixed.  Thanks